# How do I access properties using useSelector with Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-thunk

I'm trying to access the Contacts from the state but I'm always getting the whole state.

I've tried destructuring but that doesn't work either?

My slice contains toolkit and thunk.

```
export interface Contact {
  name: string;
  phone: string;
  id: number;
}
export interface contactSliceState {
  contacts: Contact[];
  status: "idle" | "pending" | "succeeded" | "failed";
  loading: boolean;
}
```

```
const contacts: Contact[] = useSelector<contactSliceState, Contact[]>(  
    (state) => state.contacts  
  );
```

```
console.log("contacts", contacts)
```

```
contacts:  
0: {name: "John", phone: "123012", id: 1}
1: {name: "Bill", phone: "653722", id: 2}
2: {name: "Tom", phone: "874932", id: 3}
loading: false
status: "succeeded"
```

[image]

Comment: isn't `contacts` an array?

Comment: Do a `console.log(state)` in the useSelector function to check the real shape of the state because something isn't adding up here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you might be giving the Typescript compiler incorrect information about the shape of your state. Since `contacts` is just a slice, you should provide the shape of the *root* state as the first generic to `useSelector`. Then I believe it will make a lot more sense:

```js
const contacts = useSelector<RootState, Contact[]>(  
    (state) => state.contacts.contacts
  );
```

Note that what I'm calling the "root" state is just the top-level state including all slices (I'm assuming the `contacts` is a key of the top-level state.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer - however, now my contacts are undefined on initial render. Not sure why it hasn't caught the intialState but that's another problem.